# Command-line alias for Visual Studio Code on OS X with CSH?

Tags: macos, bash, visual-studio-code

The [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) editor is nice, and I'm looking forward to using it to learn a bit more about javascript and node.js. The [installation instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup) describe the setup for `bash`-like shells, but I am a savage and would like to use it with `csh`. I can probably hack something together, but is there an obvious translation of

```
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* }
```

into a `csh` `alias`?

I think this sort of works:

```
alias code "setenv VSCODE_CWD ${PWD} && open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*"
```

but I think I really want a way to make `VSCODE_CWD` "local" to the alias, as in the bash version.

Comment: Well, this is no longer a relevant specific question, since VS Code now comes with an explicit `code` command-line tool, but I now realise that the right answer is to use `env`. Untested, but it's probably just `alias code "env VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*"`

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a `code` script in your `PATH` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*
```

Comment: No, that wouldn't quite work. That just defines the bash alias which isn't accessible to csh. I think you just want the part inside the curly braces...